# What mechanisms exist for Korean-Chinese to leave Korea and return to China?

Tags: china, north-korea

### Context

In [China urges citizens in N. Korea to return home](http://www.koreatimes.co.kr/www/nation/2017/05/103_228651.html):

> The Chinese Embassy in North Korea has advised Korean-Chinese
> residents to return home amid concern that the North's military
> provocations may trigger a U.S. attack on the North, according to a
> source.
>
> The embassy began sending the message on Apr. 20, five days before the
> North celebrated the 85th anniversary of the Korean People's Army with
> a show of military power, Radio Free Asia said Tuesday.

---

### Why I'm asking

It is clear that it is illegal for Freedom of Movement for North Korean people to leave as stated in [The People’s Challenges](http://www.libertyinnorthkorea.org/learn-nk-challenges/).

> **No Freedom of Movement**
>
> It is illegal for the **North Korean people to leave their country
> without the regime’s permission**, and the regime attempts to restrict
> the people’s movement even inside their own country. If you wish to
> travel to another part of the country, you are supposed to have a
> specific purpose and obtain permission from your work unit. If you do
> not live in Pyongyang, the showcase capital where most resources are
> concentrated, you will likely be denied access. The regime has also
> forcibly relocated hundreds of thousands of North Koreans to less
> favorable parts of the country as a form of punishment and political
> persecution.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

and also by [Human Rights Watch in their World Report](https://www.hrw.org/world-report/2016/country-chapters/north-korea#3cd65b)

> The government uses threats of detention, forced labor, and public
> executions to ensure obedience and imposes harsh restrictions on
> freedom of information and movement. It criminalizes leaving the
> country without official permission, and **in some instances state
> security services actively pursue North Koreans into China**, seeking to
> detain and forcibly return them.
>
> During Kim Jong-Un’s rule, the
> government has significantly expanded efforts to **stop irregular
> crossings of North Koreans into China.** The government has increased
> rotations of North Korean border guards, cracked down on brokers who
> assist people trying to leave, and **prosecuted use of Chinese cell
> phones to communicate with the outside world**. North Koreans who left
> the country in 2014 and 2015 told Human Rights Watch that the
> government was tracking down and publicly executing border guards who
> allowed people to cross into China in exchange for bribes.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

---

### Question

Does China have an agreement/policy (being [N Korea's biggest ally](http://www.newsweek.com/china-north-korea-trump-allies-economy-583883)) for such actions to take place (if so, *what is it*?) or would they have to escape?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To clarify, the article mentioned "Korean-Chinese residents" which doesn't necessarily translate to dual Korean and Chinese citizen. It likely refer to either **those who reside in both China and North Korea** OR **Chinese citizens who are of Korean descent**, though it's unclear who the article's referring to. However, both scenarios would mean that they ***only* hold Chinese citizenship**.

Furthermore, China [does not allow dual citizenship](https://www.gov.hk/en/residents/immigration/chinese/law.htm), which means it's unlikely that Chinese citizens can get Korean citizenship:

> Article 3: The People’s Republic of China does not recognise dual nationality for any Chinese national.

---

The restriction on the freedom of movement that you mention only applies to North Koreans. The Chinese embassy "has advised Korean-Chinese residents" to return home, which means that they are Chinese citizens and thus they are foreigners in North Korea. The restrictions would not apply to them.